# laser_scan_matcher crash

Tags: ros, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
When I use laser_scan_matcher everything works well for about 5-10 minutes, then the module crashes with the following output:

```
[laser_scan_matcher_node-1] process has died [pid 6944, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/scan_tools/laser_scan_matcher/bin/laser_scan_matcher_node scan:=/my_robot_bridge/laser_out odom:=/my_robot_bridge/odometry_out __name:=laser_scan_matcher_node __log:=/home/user/.ros/log/57fa5eac-28cd-11e2-b8c6-00221522c9d6/laser_scan_matcher_node-1.log].
log file: /home/user/.ros/log/57fa5eac-28cd-11e2-b8c6-00221522c9d6/laser_scan_matcher_node-1*.log
```

I searched for the log file in the suggested path, but I was not able to find it. Do you have any other suggestion to understand what's going on?

Additional info:
I don't know if it is related, but when I start the laser_scan_matcher I get the following warnings (but the module works correctly)

```
core service [/rosout] found
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[laser_scan_matcher_node-1]: started with pid [6944]
[ INFO] [1352310705.912643992]: Starting LaserScanMatcher
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

Additional info about my system:
I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS distro fuerte. For the installation of laser_scan_matcher I followed the instructions reported here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/scan_tools?distro=fuerte.
Currently I'm using the following parameters:

```
<node pkg="laser_scan_matcher" type="laser_scan_matcher_node" 
name="laser_scan_matcher_node" output="screen" args="scan:=/my_robot_bridge/laser_out">
<param name="fixed_frame" value = "odom"/>
<param name="base_frame" value="base_link"/>
<param name="use_alpha_beta" value="true"/>
<param name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
<param name="max_iterations" value="10"/>
<param name="use_imu" value="false"/>
<param name="use_odom" value="false"/>
</node>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47723/laser_scan_matcher-crash/) by [randaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1321/randaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2012-11-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2012-11-07**:
Could you give a little more information: ros version, os version, etc. Also, the which version of the scan matcher are you using?

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2012-11-07**:
Is the problem reproducible? Have you tried running laser_scan_matcher_node in a debugger (such as gdb) to see exactly where it dies?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-08**:
[relevant tutorial for running nodes in gdb](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB)

**Comment by [randaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1321/randaz/) on 2012-11-08**:
I got the following output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7a2ee6d in alloc_int_array (n=1080, def=-1)
at /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/scan_tools/csm/build/csm-git/sm/csm/laser_data.c:29
29                      v[i] = def;
```

maybe a memory leak?

**Comment by [randaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1321/randaz/) on 2012-11-08**:
confirmed memory leak (I see the consumed ram constantly increasing, >1Gb in few minutes)

**Comment by [randaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1321/randaz/) on 2012-11-17**:
Any updates from the developers about this issue? Should I submit a ticket on github? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Confirmed memory leak (introduced in a recent commit). Just fixed it.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2